# OpenCV: Reading a YAML file into a CvMat structure

Tags: c++, c, opencv, yaml

Using OpenCV, saving a CvMat structure into a YAML file on the disk is easy with

```
CvMat* my_matrix = cvCreateMat( row_no, col_no, CV_32FC1 ); 
cvSave("filename.yml", my_matrix);
```

However, I couldn't find an easy way to read the saved files back from the disk. Is there function in OpenCV that can handle this and create a CvMat structure from a YAML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CvMat* my_matrix;
my_matrix = (CvMat*)cvLoad("filename.yml");
```

seems to do the trick!